# Не подстраивается обратная связь на OpenCart, что бы сообщения уходили от администратора?

Tags: php, opencart

вчера целый день возился с обратной связью, не понимаю в чем проблема, весь интернет пересмотрел, все правильно настроил, а отдача от обратной связи другая.
Вопрос в том, что есть стандартный вывод обратной связи в раздел контакты, от туда заполняет человек данные (имя, email и сообщение), и данные которые приходят администратору на email в "от кого" указывается его почта которую он ввел при заполнении формы, но это по сути фишинг, но суть такая, что из за этого сообщения, если пользователь ввел почту с доменом mail.ru не приходят из за их политики, покажу часть кода из файла /catalog/controller/information/contact.php , может там что то не так, но весь интернет гласит, что это правильный код что бы сообщения приходили от админа, а не от почты пользователя. а у меня приходит от пользователя, и еще кэш модификаторов чистил

```
if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
  $mail = new Mail();
  $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
  $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
  $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
  $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
  $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
  $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

        $mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
        $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
        $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        $mail->setReplyTo($this->request->post['email']);
        $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf($this->language->get('email_subject'), $this->request->post['name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $message = '<p>Имя: '.$this->request->post['name'].'</p>';//добавляем имя
        $message .= '<p>Email: '.$this->request->post['email'].'</p>';//добавляем email
        $message .= '<p>Cообщение: '.$this->request->post['enquiry'].'</p>';// и сообщение
        $mail->setHtml($message);
  $mail->send();

  $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('information/contact/success'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть нюансы, в зависимости от версии OpenCart, но общий принцип такой. Правки необходимо внести в файл контроллера обратной связи: `catalog/controller/information/contact.php`

Меняем: `$mail->setFrom($this->request->post['email']);`

на: `$mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));`